# BLENDER: PNG Images on Surfaces Render Good while Rendering, then turn to Black and White with Black outlines on Final Render

Tags: rendering

PNG Images on Surfaces Render Good while Rendering, then turn to Black and White with Black outlines on Final Render.

And add a small black outline as well. I've added images with the material nodes and a few closeups...

How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put Alpha output in Alpha input

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm for the sunflower... The only thing that is still there, however, are the black outlines around everything... You can see those in the bottom right image on the one I submitted above. Any idea what is going on there or how to remove them? And thank you very much for the node correction... : )